# Maximum number of arguments for qdbusxml2cpp

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am extending a DBus interface on a linux build machine using Qt. The existing interface works fine and I need to add another parameter

The XML generation method generation is:

```
<method name="get_card_info">
  <arg type="b" name="success" direction="out" />      
  <arg type="s" name="version" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="serial" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="BeginDate" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="ExpirationDate" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="RenewalDate" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="ZipCode" direction="out" />
  <arg type="s" name="ZipCodeExtension" direction="out" />
  <!--  <arg type="u" name="cardStatus" direction="out" />  -->
</method>
```

The code works fine until I uncomment the commented out line, at which point qdbusxml2cpp reports:

```
interface_dbus_p.h:39:103: error: wrong number of template arguments (9, should be 8)
```

This is even if I comment out all calls to this function; indeed this is before the linking code even gets compiled; this is all from the **qdbusxml2cpp** call.

The XML will compile if I change this to six, seven or eight items, but if I increase it to nine it crashes.

I've changed no other configuration files except the XML code.

What's wrong? Is there a limit of eight parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it; yes there is a limit, thanks to [QDBusPendingReply](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdbuspendingreply.html#details)

*"The QDBusPendingReply is a template class with up to 8 template parameters. Those   parameters are the types that will be used to extract the contents of the reply's data."*

So no more than 8 parameters for me :(